# wp-remote-post returns Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: php, wordpress, http-post

My code is:

```
$vku_answer = wp_remote_post('https://server.vkonnektu.com/api/login', [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
    'body' => [
        'login' => 'silversv2@icloud.com',
        'password' => '123456'
    ]
]);
```

returns in `$vku_answer.body`:
{"":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: l. Path '', line 0, position 0."]}

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for `wp_remote_post` said - 'body' param is array.
It's not true at least for json - body array should be wrapped by json_encode / wp_json_encode. So, in this case body = string !